# How to wrap e2e steps in function and run it from one tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have more than 1000 lines of test steps in smoke test like this :

```
test("Smoke Test", async (t) => {
  console.log("Starting test");
// want to take out this in another class AuthStep.
  await AuthPage.setUserName("testtest@hotmail.com"); // AuthPage - page object model
  await AuthPage.setUserPassword("123456");
//end of AuthClass
  await t.expect(getUrl()).eql(authUrl);
  await t.expect(getUrl()).eql(loginUrl + "auth", { timeout: 100000 });
  await MainPage.setUserType(userName);
 ....
}
```

I just want to optimize this Smoke test and for example, move these steps into separate classes that will runs in the in Smoketest. How can I do it in TestCafe framework?

Comment: what testing framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White TestCafe

Comment: You could move those steps to a separate function, then call them from the beforeEach hook `fixture('xx').page('yy').beforeEach(async () => { await loginUser(); await assertAuthUrl(); });`